# Why the Authorization header is missing in tus-js-client?

Tags: javascript, spring-cloud-gateway, tus

I have a [tusd](https://github.com/tus/tusd) dockerized as follows:

```
  tusd-addressfull:
    image: my-tusd
    environment:
      - FILE_SERVICE_URL
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${S3_ACCESS_KEY}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${S3_SECRET_KEY}
      - AWS_REGION=${S3_REGION}
      - KEYCLOAK_URI
      - KEYCLOAK_REALM
      - TUSD_CLIENT_ID
      - TUSD_CLIENT_SECRET
      - TUSD_BUCKET=addressfull
      - BASE_HOST
    command: ["-s3-endpoint=${S3_ENDPONINT}", "-s3-bucket=addressfull", "-base-path=/files/addressfull"]
    depends_on:
      - file-service
```

And I would access it behind [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/), by:

```
        #TUSD
        - id: tusd-addressfull
          uri: http://tusd-addressfull:1080
          predicates:
            - Path=/files/addressfull/**
          filters:
            - name: RequestSize
              args:
                maxSize: 2GB
```

The Spring Cloud Gateway accepts authenticated requests with Keycloak.

In my front-end example I'm using:

```
    // Create a new tus upload
    let upload = new tus.Upload(file, {
        // endpoint: "https://mydomain/files/upload",
        endpoint: "http://mydomain/files/addressfull",

        headers: {
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${keycloak.token}`,
        },
        retryDelays: [0, 3000, 5000, 10000, 20000],
        metadata: {
            filename: file.name,
            filetype: file.type,
            test: "test"
        },
        onError: function(error) {
            console.log("Failed because: " + error)
        },
        onProgress: function(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) {
            let percentage = (bytesUploaded / bytesTotal * 100).toFixed(2)
            console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, percentage + "%")
        },
        onSuccess: function() {
            console.log("Download %s from %s", upload.file.name, upload.url)
        }
    })
```

But when I sent the upload request `OPTIONS` pass with `200` but `POST` method says `401 Unauthorized` and if I check the `Authorization: Bearer TOKEN` header isn't present in `POST`.

Seems as [this issue](https://github.com/tus/tus-js-client/issues/122).

Why?

What am I missing out?